# Angular bootstrap datetimepicker disable "time"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular bootstrap datetimepicker:
https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I am going to disable "time", want to enable only date.
I am using this option:

```
<datetimepicker ng-model="pageData.currentNote.date" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown', startView:'day', minView:'day' }"></datetimepicker>
```

Time select Panel is removed , but I am getting time field:

> Thu Sep 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

I don't want time field. Any solution to remove this?

Comment: you can using javascript to format datetime.https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Answer (score 1):

This control you have selected looks like a date time picker specific to its function of selecting a date and then a time.

You should really look into https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and specifically https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker

This is a great toolset to use for Angular 1

Comment: @lan Roberts-It's really great! Thanks!

Comment: Is there any great datepicker for AngularJS and bootstrap3?

Comment: @Deimos620 this is for angular1 and Bootstrap 3. If you are using Angular 2 then you must use ng-bootstrap (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). Otherwise, this is the correct toolset for Angular 1 and Bootstrap 3.